# Proper way to add an AutoSuggestBox to Hamburger Navigation?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

I'm just starting to learn UWP and xaml. What is the proper way to add a AutoSuggestBox to the Side Navigation panel? (Sorry for the bad code formatting in advance, copy and paste wasn't great)

My Main.xaml has an AutoSuggestArea that I have set to Visible

```
</VisualStateGroup>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AutoSuggestGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxVisible"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxCollapsed">
  <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="AutoSuggestArea.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

and in the Grid for the AutoSuggestArea I have defined an AutoSuggestBox

```
<Grid x:Name="AutoSuggestArea" Height="44" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center">

<ContentControl x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding AutoSuggestBox}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="16,0,16,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

<Button x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestButton" Content="&#xE11A;" MinHeight="44" Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"/>

    <AutoSuggestBox Width="234" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       PlaceholderText="Search" Name ="boxS"                            
       QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted" 
       TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged">
        <AutoSuggestBox.TextBoxStyle>
          <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="IsHandwritingViewEnabled" Value="False"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
      </AutoSuggestBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
          <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find" Foreground="Black">                                                   
             <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
             <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>                                         
             </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
          </SymbolIcon>
       </AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
</Grid>
```

What I want is basically Identical Behaviour as the Groove Music app on Windows, where the Search bar disappears as the Nav View is closed or Minimized.

[image]

Instead I get this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you meant `NavigationView` by `NavigationPanel`.

This is not how you put an `AutoSuggestBox` in `NavigationView`. `NavigationView` has an [`NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.autosuggestbox) property. You just set an `AutoSuggestBox` on this property, and every thing will work as expected. Like this:

```
<NavigationView>
    <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="NavViewSearchBox" QueryIcon="Find"/>
    </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
</NavigationVew>
```

You don't have to hide/show this `AutoSuggestBox` yourself. `NavigationView` will automatically do this for you. Also, you don't have to put thie `AutoSuggestBox` inside any grid or anything.